# What is the difference between preconfigure and configure in glibc?

Tags: glibc

There are both preconfigure(.in) and configure(.in) scripts under the corresponding sysdeps/"architecture" directories within glibc source files.
So anyone who know about their difference！？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preconfigure` files were used by the add-on mechanism to override information used by the `configure` script:

> The real source code for any ports is found in the sysdeps/ subdirectories. These should be exactly what would go into the main libc source tree if you were to incorporate it directly.  The only exceptions are the files sysdeps/*/preconfigure and sysdeps/*/preconfigure.in; these are fragments used by this add-on's configure fragment.  The purpose of these is to set $base_machine et al when the main libc configure's defaults are not right for some machine.  Everything else can and should be done from a normal sysdeps/.../configure fragment that is used only when the configuration selects that sysdeps subdirectory.  Each port that requires some special treatment before the sysdeps directory list is calculated, should add a sysdeps/CPU/preconfigure file; this can either be written by hand or generated by Autoconf from sysdeps/CPU/preconfigure.in, and follow the rules for glibc add-on configure fragments.  No preconfigure file should do anything on an unrelated configuration, so that disparate ports can be put into a single add-on without interfering with each other.

(From an old version of the `README` file.)

The need for this went away when the `ports` subdirectory was removed, and the add-on mechanism is almost completely unused today.

Comment: Thanks ！
In fact, this question I mean was why these contents in preconfigure scripts were not directly put into their own disparate configure scripts underlying  the corresponding  <machine> subdir of ports/sysdeps ！？

Comment: The `preconfigure` fragments could influence what the main configure code (outside ports/sysdeps) would do. Today, we'd make the necessary changes directly in the main configure code, but for ports/add-ons, this wasn't possible because they were separate.

Comment: Yes, you are right！
    I have reviewed the main configure script,  it contains the code of checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments.